# Clusters with k-means having bad results

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset with 60 000 rows and 19 columns ( I will leave a sample below) and I am trying to make clusters.
Using the k-means algorithm I am getting a very low score.

### Dataset Sample

[image]

Since some of my columns are categorical variables I proceded to transform them in continous using dictionaries variables as follows:

```
def education_dict(data):
    education_dict= {
        "Bachelors": 0,
        "Graduate Degree": 1,
        "High School": 2,
        "Partial College": 3,
        "Partial High School": 4
    }
    data["IDEducation"]=data["Education"].map(education_dict)
```

After converting the categorical variable to a continuous variable I delete the old variable.

After that I do the normalization of the data ( all columns since now all of them are continuous) and I proceed to the k-means algorithm.

```
mms=MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(data)
Xnorm=mms.transform(data)
print(Xnorm.min(axis=0))
print(Xnorm.max(axis=0))
print(Xnorm.shape)

km=KMeans(n_clusters=10,n_init=1000,max_iter=800,random_state=42)
y_kmeans=km.fit_predict(Xnorm)

#Clustering evaluation
#Silhouette score

#the closest to 1 the better
silSc=silhouette_score(data,y_kmeans,metric="euclidean")
print("Silhouette score: " , round(silSc,3))
print("\nThese measures need grand truth\n")
```

The cluster evaluation is returning me a silhouette score of about 0.08 and this is to low.
If I run hieraquical clustering, which is not suited to big datasets like mine, I get a score of about 0.54

```
segmentation=["single","average","complete"]
results=[]
for met in segmentation:
    distance_matrix=linkage(Xnorm,method=met,metric="euclidean")
    #Assign cluster lables
    cluster_labels=fcluster(distance_matrix,3,criterion="maxclust")

    silSc=silhouette_score(data,cluster_labels,metric="euclidean")
    print("Silhouette score: " , round(silSc,3))
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Clustering algos simply do what you would expect them to do. They are unsupervised learners. Nevertheless, you can find the accuracy of a clustering algo. See the link below for details.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering algos simply do what you would expect them to do. They are unsupervised learners. Nevertheless, you can find the accuracy of a unsupervised algo, similar to supervised learning. See the link below for details.

https://smorbieu.gitlab.io/accuracy-from-classification-to-clustering-evaluation/

Now, I think you should try several clustering algos on your given data set, and see which performs optimally. See the link below for several samples of different clustering algos.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/clustering-algorithms-with-python/

Just set different models, fit each model, and check the output of each one. Finally, I see that you are scaling your data. That's great! It's of utmost importance to scale the data before doing K-means clustering, or any algorithm that uses distances. Without scaling, features on a larger scale will weight more heavily in the algorithm. All features should weigh equally at the initial stage.